# Unable to retrieve the enum members in the order they have been defined!

Tags: .net, enums, enumeration

We have an enum with members having random values, say

```
enum MyEnum
{
    enumMember1 = 100,
    enumMember2 = 10,
    enumMember3 = 50
}
```

We couldnt iterate through the enum members in the order they have been defined! `Enum.GetValues` and `Enum.GetNames` both internally sort the members and gives the result!

iterating the array returned by Enum.GetNames or Enum.GetValues and doing a `.ToString()` on each of the array elements gives us,

```
enumMember2, enumMember3, enumMember100.
```

Was just wondering if there is any out of the box approach to get the enum members in the order they have been created? Did search, didnt get much info!  Thanks!

P.S. I would hate to get this done through a custom attribute!
And While drafting it, i had a doubt if the IL for enum gets generated after sorting the Enum members, going to check it ryt away!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
var values = typeof(MyEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                 .Select (x => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.Name));
```

Comment: Yes, the reflection way works! Wish the Enum.GetNames atleast preserved the order in which the enum was declared! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067493/if-getfields-doesnt-guarantee-order-how-does-layoutkind-sequential-work I would refer to this link as GetFields(..) may not always return in the correct order. the post has a different solution

Comment: `Enum.GetNames`[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx] method remarks: The elements of the return value array are sorted by the binary values of the enumerated constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude)