# if GetFields() doesn't guarantee order, how does LayoutKind.Sequential work

Tags: c#, reflection, marshalling

I need to get fieldinfo in a guaranteed order with respect to declaration order. Right now I'm using attributes to specify order.

Is there a more automatic way of doing this?

Does anyone have knowledge of how `LayoutKind.Sequential` works, and if I can apply its technique.

I don't see how `LayoutKind.Sequential` works, unless there's some precompiler code that adds attributes.

Comment: +1. I'm interested in seeing this, too.

Comment: This is to automate marshalling where the custom marshaller fails to guarantee size on objects with varying native size. (get size on custom marshaller doesn't give you an pointer to actual data or structure to operate on in cases where an object can have varying native size). So if say I wanted to prepend an size or count to any array or string, I have to do it manually, since I can't do it with a custom marshaller and ask the object for it's native data size.

Comment: This only makes a statement about the implementation of GetFields(), not about the way the CLR implements member layout.  The caching of reflection data is the trouble.  Significantly revised in .NET 2 btw, not so sure it is still true.

Comment: Metadata can be (and I suspect is, and have evidence that it is) independent of how it is arranged in managed memory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want the ordering of the fields returned by `Type.GetFields`  to be stable, try sorting by the [`MetadataToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken.aspx) property.

```
Type myType = ...
BindingFlags flags = ...
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> orderedFields = myType.GetFields(flags)
                                             .OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);
```

Empirically, ordering fields in this manner has been found to [return them in declaration order](http://www.signumframework.com/MemberInfoIssue.ashx), **although this isn't documented**.

By the way, the question as asked doesn't entirely make sense; there isn't any reason to believe that the reflection API is tied in any way to how the runtime lays objects out in memory.

Comment: I don't care how the objects are laid out in managed memory. All I want is a way to guarantee an order so I can arrange things in native memory. An order specifier is enough, even if this isn't reflected in managed layout order. As a matter of fact, I would prefer the two not be tied together.

Comment: I get your question now. Updated question to say "guaranteed declaration order"

Comment: Are metadata tokens in order even if Sequential is not specified?

Comment: ECMA 335 does say "A class marked `sequentiallayout` guides the loader to preserve field order as emitted", which means in the order they are in the "Field" metadata table, and so the order of their `MetadataToken`. So I'd say this trick is more or less documented.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14606 confirms this answer to work. It also confirms the class/struct must be sequentiallayout.

Answer (score 12):

The question is old but not so old... I'm dealing now with the same problem. And I prefer to get the fields in tho order of declaration. The following call should work for a value type or a formatted reference type.

```
var fields = type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32());
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Be sure to specific LayoutSequential though.

If you don't, the Marshalling occurs in whatever order it prefers, and offset is by that order.

Though, this would work if MetadataToken solution starts failing.

Comment: The use of `LayoutKind.Sequential` is mentioned in your own question, so I considered a precondition for my answer. As already stated, the use of `MetadataToken` is officially undocumented and unsupported, even if probably give the right results for the actual state of knowledge. My answer, on the other hand, is officially documented and supported.

Comment: No, I appreciate it. The moment my method stops working, I'm implementing this. Link is bookmarked.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but, does anyone know how to actually force GetFields() to list the properties in incorrect order, for me to fix by using the method above. Right now, GetFields gives me everything in the right order every time. So, I have no proof I am fixing the problem.

Comment: You cannot force `GetFields()` to return _fields_ in a whatever order. But you can sort the result of the call in a _wrong_ order and then sort again in the _right_ order. For example, you can compare `type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => f.Name)`, which sort fields alphabetically, and `type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => f.Name).OrderBy(f => Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32())`, which hopefully give the _correct_ order.

Answer (score 0):

[LayoutKind.Sequential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) specifies that the fields of the type should be laid out in memory in the same order they are declared in your source code.

Without the attribute the CLR is free to optimize memory use by rearranging the fields.

So the attribute just adds metadata that tells the CLR not to do any in memory optimalisation that messes up the order of fields.

Comment: do you exactly what? I'm know.
but like most metadata, you can probably access it using reflect.
see [MemberInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx), and you can probably get it by using `GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LayoutKind))`

Comment: -1, as this does not answer the question; it only explains what `LayoutKind.Sequential` is, which is not in question here.

Comment: Except per MSDN this only applies to marshalling, not layout in managed memory, which is controlled by the CLR.