# How to get the first enum value irrespective of the sign?

Tags: c#

How can you get the 1st enum member only using its Type irrespective of whether underlying value is positive or negative?

Lets assume I have an enum like this:

```
public enum GamePeriod
{
    Unknown = -100,
    PreGame = 0,
    Q1 = 1,
    Q2 = 2,
    Q3 = 3,
    Q4 = 4,
    OT = 5,
    Completed = 6,
}
```

How can I make sure to always get Unknown? Irrespective of whether its value is -1, -10, -100, 100, 666 or anything else?

Comment: Get what? It's name as a string? The default value when you declare it? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why are you turning an `enum` into a magic number?

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? You would just use `GamePeriod.Unknown`. Please give an example.

Comment: You are getting it like GamePeriod.Unknown .... and you want to be sure the you get Unknown? :)

Comment: Do you want to do that using reflection, given a `Type` parameter ?...

Comment: I think he means if you do `var period = (GamePeriod)24` then`period == GamePeriod.Unkown`  should return true. My suggesion is to create a utility method to convert any invalid value to GamePeriod.Unknown aka -100.

Comment: I'd ask **why** you need that but to directly answer to your question: **no, you can't** because enum values are always returned sorted by their value (no matters order in which they're declared). BTW sorting is done unsigned so negative values will also be in _wrong_ order.

Comment: I'm not sure you are going about this in the correct way, it doesn't make sense to actually have an `enum` value that represents an "unknown" value. The entire definition of it being unknown infers the *opposite* in that it *shouldn't* exist in the `enum`. It's better to throw & handle the appropriate exception in this circumstance and return an appropriate default (or alternatively let the exception bubble up).

Comment: Not sure why is my question so difficult to understand for most people. I mean exactly what I said. I need to get the first member of enum type by its type. 1st enum member being GamePeriod.Unknown.

Comment: Let me [repeat myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671132/how-to-get-the-first-enum-value-irrespective-of-the-sign/30671250#comment49404565_30671132): `Enum.GetValues()` and `Enum.GetNames()` will order their result according to enum values (and because of a known bug treating value as unsigned then in your example first value is `PreGame`). Then answer is **no**: you can't know which one has been declared first unless you decorate such value with an attribute.

Comment: @Adrianno Yes, your answer addresses my problem exactly. Unfortunately it doesnt solve it. I am aware of this answer. The reason I posted the question here was in hope that someone might know a trick I am not aware of. Not even sure why this question gets downvoted so much. Most people never had to encounter such a situation?

Comment: What is usually done (if you don't want to use an attribute) is to use _default_ value as _unknown_/_uninitialized_ (`0` or better `null`). As alternative you may drop `enum` and use `struct`s (like `System.Drawing.Color` does) but probably problem is what you're trying to do not in `enum` itself.

Comment: @James, changing the enum design is not an option, I need to support a legacy code.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Seems like there is no solution for this one.

Comment: @Tanuki in that case it's pretty simple, check if the enum [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if not then return a default value i.e. `GamePeriod.Unknown`. Alternatively, as suggested catch an exception and return a default in that way - either or it's going to involve some logic.

Comment: @Thank you James, this is actually a good workaround, although not exactly an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var min = ((GamePeriod[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(GamePeriod))).Min();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer and achieves exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this gives you what you need? Isn't the idea you want to provide a value which is then parsed and would yield `Unknown` if it doesn't exist? This answer simply enumerates all the values and returns the one with the smallest value.

Comment: @James I think I incorrectly got the question and now I am also confused

Comment: @Tanuki, please clarify, I think I incorrecly got you. This will return minimum value of enum values not the one you first placed in enum.

Comment: @James and Giorgi. Yes, actually the problem I had was solved exactly by the Giorgi's answer, although now that I look back at the question the problem I asked was broader than just that. In the broad terms James answer solve the underlying problem better. So if both of you dont mind I could change the accepted answer to James one (provided he answers it as a separate answer)

Comment: Of course, you should accept answer that most fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been answered before:
[if GetFields() doesn't guarantee order, how does LayoutKind.Sequential work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067493/if-getfields-doesnt-guarantee-order-how-does-layoutkind-sequential-work)

```
Type myType = ...
BindingFlags flags = ...
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> orderedFields = myType.GetFields(flags)
                                             .OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);
```

However it's better to use some other way of having a special value.

Null usually works.

```
 GamePeriod? p = ...

 if (p == null)
 {
     // special case 
 }
 else
 {
     UseAsNormal(p.Value);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but changing design is not option for me.