# Convert Object To Byte Array without Serialization nor Padding

Tags: c#

It seems easy but I can't see it easy at all. My question is I have a struct and I need to convert it to byte stream without any additional bytes for types nor padding nor metadata. Assume I have a struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public ushort a;                 
    public uint b;  
    public uint c;
    public ushort d;
}
```

**Remark:** I can't change the pack here to 1(Project constrains), so using the following solution **won't work** as there's a padding added

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
byte[] arr = new byte[size];
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

**Also Remark:** I can't use Binary format serialization as there's a metadata added.  All what I want simply if a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 to get binary format in a **GENERIC WAY** as

```
    arr {byte[12]}  byte[]
    [0]  1  byte
    [1]  0  byte
    [2]  2  byte
    [3]  0  byte
    [4]  0  byte
    [5]  0  byte
    [6]  3  byte
    [7]  0  byte
    [8]  0  byte
    [9]  0  byte
    [10] 4  byte
    [11] 0  byte
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried manually creating that array with `BitConverter`?

Comment: Manually of course will work I need something generic

Comment: If you sprinkle a bit of reflection magic over it ([`GetFields`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067493/if-getfields-doesnt-guarantee-order-how-does-layoutkind-sequential-work)) it would be very generic.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I tried that but I was not able find a complete solution if you have a snip of code to do so you can post it

Comment: Does the struct only have simple fields ? Or can it have nested structs or arrays ?

Comment: @lain the way you suggested is same what I posted and it won't work as it will add a padding

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it can contains array

Comment: If you can't use the standard solutions you need to roll your own.

Comment: @tulipe if your data includes an array: you can forget it  - now you're talking about multiple objects, which means you're going to need to define what it should look like when you pack the data; there's no de-facto way of storing multiple objects or arrays (how is the range of the array demarked, for example). The only thing that has an automatic native representation is the layout of a single struct (or a vector of such structs). Fixed buffers inside structs work; arrays don't.

Comment: @MarcGravell you can forget about the array I'm looking for a solution on a the above struct or similar one

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of manual work, you can write your own converter and handle each datatype differently, for example:

```
public static class StructSerializer
{
    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T data) where T : struct
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
        Type type = data.GetType();
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> orderedFields = type.GetFields().OrderBy(f => Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32());

        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in orderedFields)
        {
            object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(data);
            MethodInfo conversion = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod(nameof(BitConverter.GetBytes), new[]{fieldInfo.FieldType});
            if (conversion == null) continue;
            byte[] converted = (byte[])conversion.Invoke(null, new []{value});
            result.AddRange(converted);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

You didn't specifically mention it, but keep the ByteOrder in mind. You can check the byte order with `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any guarantees from the CLI that would make `MetadataToken` a sensible thing to order by, especially if you want it to keep working between builds

Comment: @MarcGravell Unfortunatly, yes. I just took this info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067702/3214843), maybe I can find something in the reference source that would work a bit better.

Comment: ooh, that's gnarly; completely undocumented (or at least: informally documented via github), and only known to work in some cases (specifically: `LayoutKind.Sequential`), but indeed it looks like it might work, but... shudder!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Explicit layout to define exactly how you want the array to be formed:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort a;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public uint b;
        [FieldOffset(6)]
        public uint c;
        [FieldOffset(10)]
        public ushort d;
    }
```

But of course its not at all generic

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted - this very concisely solves the exact problem and gives the expected output

Comment: As for Pack, OP explicitly states in question that he cannot use Pack=1 (because of some project requirements). I guess he cannot use FieldOffset either then (though of course I didn't downvote).

Comment: @Evk 1 He didn't explicitly state that when I wrote my answer.  Its a more recent edit.  may still be a useful answer to someone in the future though.

Comment: @Tim I did not make any update to the question, I have not devoted it :)

Comment: @tulipe Ah sorry I missed that bit when I first read it then.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I may have misunderstood the question; if your point is that you want the *specific layout* - then see the `FieldOffset` hints that [Tim Rutter notes in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47649976/23354).

---

`unsafe` might be the easiest option:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class P
{
    private static unsafe void Main()
    {
        MyStruct orig = new MyStruct { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 };

        byte[] raw = new byte[sizeof(MyStruct)];
        // write the empty array to prove it is empty
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(raw));


        // serialize
        fixed (byte* p = raw)
        {
            var typed = (MyStruct*)p;
            *typed = orig;
        }

        // write the serialized data
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(raw));

        // deserialize
        MyStruct clone;
        fixed (byte* p = raw)
        {
            var typed = (MyStruct*)p;
            clone = *typed;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"a = {clone.a}, b = {clone.b}, c = {clone.c}, d = {clone.d}");
    }
}
```

with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] // see Tim's answer for explicit layout
public struct MyStruct
{
    public ushort a;
    public uint b;
    public uint c;
    public ushort d;
}
```

However, it isn't very generic. If you need more generic code: the `Unsafe` type has many utility methods for this kind of thing.

Comment: That still has padding OP is trying to avoid

Comment: @Evk yes, that's why I added the edit to the top pointing to Tim's answer; however, I'm going to leave this here to illustrate how to avoid the `Marshal` usage

Comment: Why not just set Pack to 1?

Comment: @TimRutter because I addressed a tangential point - which I have acknowledged in the first line; you're already doing a great job of discussing the explicit/pack options in your answer, so there's no benefit in my duplicating that

Comment: Thats fine I thought I might have been missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable answers/comments! I have found a workaround I will remove the padding manually

```
        static byte[] getBytes<T>(T str) where T : struct
    {

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        int Pack = str.GetType().StructLayoutAttribute.Pack;
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        arr = RemovePadding<T>(arr.ToList(), str, str.GetType().StructLayoutAttribute.Pack);
        return arr;
    }
    static byte[] RemovePadding<T>(List<byte> buffer, T str, int Pack)
    {
        int largestsize = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int RowOfMemory = 0;

        //Get all fields 
        var fields = str.GetType().GetFields();

        //After MSDN
        //The alignment of the type is the size of its largest element (1, 2, 4, 8, etc., bytes) or the specified packing size, whichever is smaller.
        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            if (Marshal.SizeOf(item.FieldType) > largestsize)
                largestsize = Marshal.SizeOf(item.FieldType);
        }
        if (largestsize < Pack) Pack = largestsize;

        //Find and remove padding from all memory rows 
        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(item.FieldType);
            if (RowOfMemory != 0 && (RowOfMemory + size) > Pack)
            {
                int paddingsize = Math.Abs(Pack - RowOfMemory);
                buffer.RemoveRange(index, paddingsize);
                RowOfMemory = size % Pack;
            }
            else if ((RowOfMemory + size) < Pack)
            {
                RowOfMemory += size;
            }
            else if ((RowOfMemory + size) == Pack)
            {
                RowOfMemory = 0;
            }
            index += size;
        }
        if (RowOfMemory != 0)
        {
            int paddingsize = Math.Abs(Pack - RowOfMemory);
            buffer.RemoveRange(index, paddingsize);
        }
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
```

I will not count this as a right answer, may be someone found a better solution.